# How do i get a ball to start moving?

Tags: pygame

How do i start moving a ball around the screen in a pinball game. I tried to make the ball times by -1 when it reached the border but i don't think the code was written properly. i need the ball to move like a ball does in a normal pinball game. I'm not too familiar with collisions and such but i'm trying to learn it.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
balls = []
run = True

class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 10


def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (player1.x, player1.y, player1.width, player1.height))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (player2.x, player2.y, player2.width, player2.height))
    pygame.draw.circle(win, ball.colour, (ball.x, ball.y), ball.radius)
    pygame.display.update()


class projectile(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, colour):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.colour = colour
        self.vel = 7


ball = projectile(500, 350, 15, (225,225,225))
player1 = player(30, 275, 30, 150)
player2 = player(940, 275, 30, 150)

while run:
    clock.tick(30)
    neg = -1

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and player1.y > player1.vel:
        player1.y -= player1.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and player1.y < 700 - player1.height - player1.vel:
        player1.y += player1.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and player2.y > player2.vel:
        player2.y -= player2.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player2.y < 700 - player2.height - player2.vel:
        player2.y += player2.vel

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if ball.x > 0 and ball.y > 0:
            ball.y -= ball.vel
            ball.x -= ball.vel
        if ball.y == 1:
            ball.y *= neg

    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ball.y == 1:
    ball.y *= neg
```

This looks *very* strange, negating the *position* of the ball. It's more common to have a position and a vector (in the mathematical sense of "magnitude and direction", not the programming sense of "array") indicating how to change the position over time<sup>(a)</sup>.

For example, a ball heading right 1 with a fixed `y` position would be something like:

```
xpos = 0, ypos = 20
xincr = 1, yincr = 0
while true:
    xpos += xincr
    ypos += yincr
    drawAt(xpos, ypos)
```

Then you can adjust the vector (the `xincr` and `yincr` values) depending on conditions, such as bouncing off walls (Python-style pseudo-code):

```
xpos = radius, ypos = radius, xincr = 1, yincr = 1
while true:
    xpos += xincr, ypos += yincr
    drawAt(xpos, ypos)
    if xpos == radius or xpos == screenWidth - radius - 1:
        xincr *= -1
    if ypos == radius or ypos == screenHeight - radius - 1:
        yincr *= -1
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> And, yes, I can see you have a velocity variable but:

- It's not really split out into `x` and `y` components, making it unsuitable; and
- It never changes.